# How to delete a portion of text from a file in C++

Tags: c++, file

I want to make a todo project. In this project to save task data i want to create a data file. But i need to delete some portion of text from my data file sometimes. But can't do that.
How can i do that.

Comment: someone help...

Comment: You could load the whole file in, make the changes and write out the new version.

Comment: You can't really erase data from the middle of a file. The simple way is to create a new file, write out only the items you want to keep, and then replace the old file with the new file. Otherwise, open the existing file, seek to the item you want to delete, read a chunk of data following that item and overwrite the item with it, then keep repeating for the rest of the file, overwriting a piece of the file with a later piece from the same file, until you reach EOF, then set a new EOF following the last piece you copied. This is much harder to implement, and very inefficient on the system.

Comment: depending on the type of file, you may be able to replace the removed portion with bytes that will be ignored by a parser later (like spaces or null bytes), but again, thats totally dependent on format of the data within.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most filesystems only allow you to delete from or append to the end of a file. You can modify the data in the middle of the file but not add or remove it.

To remove data from the middle of a file you need to copy the remaining data to a new file.